# Main storyboard and Simulator shows different views

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is the screenshot of main storyboard: Instead of the main storyboard screen simulator shows a table view with a bunch of names listed image and comment section are invisible

[image]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return userEmailArray.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

        cell.useremailLabel.text = userEmailArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.likeLabel.text = String(likesArray[indexPath.row])
        cell.commentLabel.text = userCommentArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.userimageView.image = UIImage(named: "selectImage.png")



        return cell
    }
```

Comment: instead of the main storyboard screen simulator shows a table view with a bunch of names listed image and comment section are invisible

Comment: Can you please explain more about what behavior you want exactly? And what's going wrong, so people can understand you better. Thanks!

Comment: My best guess without more info is that your constraints are off. If you are using estimated height for cell then your constraints must be setup correctly. Xcode console will spit out error for constraints if it cannot find what you want to do. Otherwise my guess is the height is set in code or storyboard wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to connect the dataSource and the delegate to the view controller (or the handler for achieving it).

Programmatically:

```
myTableView.dataSource = self
myTableView.delegate = self
```

Or from the IB:

[image]